# How to delete the same table fields with an sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a hard time
I have a lot of the same table fielt when inputting
example:

```
---------------------------------<br/>
| id_pr       | id_pro   | id_cat  |
<br/>---------------------------------<br/>
| 1001        | 002      | 103     |
<br/>---------------------------------<br/>
| 1002        | 003      | 104     |
<br/>---------------------------------<br/>
| 1003        | 004      | 103     |
<br/>---------------------------------<br/>
```

id_cat field has the same data which is 103
how do i delete one of the same 103 data fields and when it is deleted
data in

```
--------------------
| 1003 | 004 | 103 |
--------------------
```

also deleted, how do I enter the sql query ?

can you help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep the smallest id using `join` with an aggregation query:

```
delete t
    from t join
         (select id_cat, min(id_pr) as min_id_pr
          from t
          group by id_cat
          having count(*) > 1
         ) tt
         on t.id_cat = tt.id_cat and t.id_pr > tt.min_id_pr
```

Comment: I tried to enter the message in mysql but an error message appeared
#1146 - Table 'data_story' doesn't exist

Comment: @urlsnort . . . You need a table that does exist, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `exists` as follows:

```
Delete from your_table t
 Where exists
       (Select 1 from your_table tt
         Where t.id_cat = tt.id_cat
           And t.id_par > tt.id_par);
```